# How to import a method from a library using the string name of the method in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, import

I can do this:

```
from sklearn import metrics
```

How can I do this?

```
the_method='metrics'
from sklearn import the_method
```

Why do I want this?

I want to import dynamically only the methods I need.

Answer (score -1):

what do you want to achieve from this , i assume you only need to alias or customize the name ? if this is the case why not trying

`from sklearn import metrics as the_method`

Comment: I do not understand your solution. I basically do not want to use the specific name of the method "metrics" and you are using. I want to call a method from a library depending on the input.

Comment: The idea I am looking for is how to import a method from a library when I provide the name by a string.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Mohamed's answer is right. I don't understand any reason where you would want to import a function to use that is stored as a string in a variable. Just simply do `from sklearn import metrics` . You could ask for an input and use an if statement to check the input and then call metrics() if appropriate.

Comment: @Nicholar_jaeger, I want to import a method that is provided as a string. In the library there are several methods, I want to import just one that is provided by a string. The answer of Mohamed is not an answer for my question. The answer Mohamed is providing allows me to call a method as usual and to refer this method using a different name provided by a string. That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I have absolutely no earthly idea why you would want to dynamically import. The difference in resources allocated is negligible.

Comment: Nicholas I am developing some classes that depend on several different libraries. I don’t want to load the entire libraries but only the methods that I need in a specific run of the code. About the resources use, I am not sure since some of the original libraries are very large.